# How do I tell Homebrew to stop running brew update every time I want to install something?

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew

Homebrew started running `brew update` automatically before every `brew install`. This means that I need to wait 10-20 seconds, depending on network speed, every time I want to install a package. This is tedious and unnecessary.

How can I opt out from this behavior, or set it to something saner?

**Update**: Good news! Homebrew 4, released on February 16 2023, [finally fixes this](https://brew.sh/2023/02/16/homebrew-4.0.0/):

> brew update will now be run automatically less often (every 24 hours rather than every 5 minutes) and these auto-updates will be much faster as they no longer need to perform the slow git fetch of the huge homebrew/core and homebrew/cask taps’ Git repositories.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Just prefix your install command with `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1`, like this:

```
HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew install somepackage
```

Source: [brew manpage](https://github.com/Homebrew/brew/blob/7d31a70373edae4d8e78d91a4cbc05324bebc3ba/Library/Homebrew/manpages/brew.1.md.erb#L202)

Answer (score 12):

I just modified `/usr/local/bin/brew` to add `HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1` (according to @D Schlachter answer) at the start of the file

Comment: Why not just add `export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1` to your `.bashrc`?

Comment: this and/or @cpcallen's comment above should be marked as the correct answer.

Comment: Why is this not the default setting? Who says, let me install something and while I am at it upgrade the other 50 things (because that certainly won't break anything)

Answer (score 5):

I personally find pinning/unpinning formulas more useful. For example you install a tool depends on 100 libraries which you don't use.

```
brew deps someprogram | xargs brew pin
```

Then you can check your pinned formulas anytime. If you have any problems with the version just unpin.

Not recommended to everyone, to pin all the formulas and manage updates manually:

```
brew list | xargs brew pin
```

Comment: What does this have to do with homebrew updating itself?

Answer (score 3):

To have brew automatically run `brew update` AFTER installing, I added the following to my bash/zsh environment:

```
function brew2() {
    HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE=1 brew "$@" && brew update
}
```

Then to install package x, I do `brew2 x`, for example `brew2 cask install spotmenu`. Seems to work.

Comment: Why want homebrew to update everything before or after install at all? "If something is working, don't fix it", yet brew is doing it. Why would it be updating mitmproxy when I only want to install mysql-client?

Comment: The best thing to do, imo, would be to auto-update everything in the background, the way apps autoupdate on phones nowadays. Something like this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/206474/308005

Answer (score 0):

I recommend installing [homebrew-autoupdate](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-autoupdate). Run: `brew tap homebrew/autoupdate`

This is a script that will automatically run `brew update` in the background once every 24 hours, or on system boot. Then you can add this line to your `~/.bashrc` (or `~/.zshrc`) to disable the built-in autoupdate mechanism:

```
export HOMEBREW_NO_AUTO_UPDATE="1"
```

You can also configure it to run more frequently in the background, for example every 12 hours (43200 seconds):

```
brew autoupdate start 43200
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).